# How to manage linked entities in a create/update Symfony2 form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have in my **Symfony2 web application** a form used to manage a shop. I want to be able to create and edit my shop using this form.
My problem is that **my Shop entity has an Adress which is an other entity I need to create in the same time I create my shop**.

The shop entity is composed like following :

```
<?php
//src/appBundle/Entity/Shop
namespace AppBundle\Entity;    
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * Shop
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_shop")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ShopRepository")
 */
class Shop
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="shopName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $shopName;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="ownerName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $ownerName;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\Seller", cascade={"refresh"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="NO ACTION")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $owner;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Address", cascade={"refresh"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="NO ACTION")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $address;

   //..getters&setters
}
```

A shop has an `Adress` and I need to create or edit this Adress entity each time I am in this Form. My adress entity is composed like this :

```
//src/appBundle/Entity/Address
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Adress
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_address")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AddressRepository")
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="street", type="string", length=255)
     * 
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5)
     */
    private $postalCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $country;

    //..getters&setters

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->street." ".$this->getPostalCode()." ".$this->getCity();
    }
}
```

I created a form to manage a shop in my registration process. My problem is that **I can't display the Address's fields as for my shop entity. I just have a select list which is displaying the adresses already existing in my database.**

```
<?php
namespace UserBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Address;

class ShopType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('shopName', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nom du magasin*', 'required' => true, 'error_bubbling' => true))
            ->add('ownerName', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nom du gérant*', 'required' => true, 'error_bubbling' => true))

            ->add('address', EntityType::class , array('class' => 'AppBundle:Address'))
        ;
    } 
}
```

In my controller I instanciate my form as following :

```
    $shop = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Shop')->findOneByOwner($user);
    if ($shop == null){
        $shop = new Shop();
    }
    $form = $this->createForm(ShopType::class , $shop);
```

In this example, I have a select list with the existing addresses like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to embed an address form inside your shop form, so you need to create a form for the Address entity and then you will be adding in your ShopType an AddressType as described here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html

If you use EntityType, you will be selecting an entity from your database to be linked (For example, think of setting a suburb/country in your Address if suburb/country was a separate entity).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for